# URL Access Security after getting URL from databse and their roles in java file

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have spring security in my `security.xml`

What I want is:

- I am getting URL and their roles from database
- now I want to give access on these URL after checking their roles in java file

How can I achieve this with spring security?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of them

@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")

or

@RolesAllowed("ROLE_ADMIN")// JSR-250’s annotation

or

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")

or

If you want to check roles from DB, you have to use Spring AOP concept

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do the same.

Solution 1 : xml configuration (`ApplicationContextSecurity.xml`)

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ROOT_ADMIN','ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER')" />
```

here you can replace ** with your URL.

Solution 2 : Put `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ROOT_ADMIN')")` on top of the controller method which is going to be called on the URL.

**NOTE : Approach 2 will be best for you as you are getting URLs from database dynamically. and approach 1 will be best when you already have url and access rights predefined.**

Comment: I am getting URL and their roles from the database.i have too gives access to URL according to its role. I want to do it in java